# Почему не находит изображение по подсказываемому IDE пути?

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

Имеется файл шаблона
template.html

```
            <menu>
                <li>
                    <span>8-800-555-29-52</span>
                    <div class="sidebar-call-icon"><img src="/src/assets/img/call-img.svg" alt=""></div>
                </li>
                
            </menu>
            
        </div>
```

конфигурация вебпака

```
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");
const TerserWebpackPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
const loader = require("sass-loader");

console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);
console.log(__dirname);
console.log(path.join(__dirname, 'src', '/assets/img/header/call-img.svg'));
const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development";
const optimization = () => {
    const config = {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: "all"
        }
    };

    if (! isDev) {
        config.minimizer = [new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin(), new TerserWebpackPlugin(),];
    }

    return config;
};

const cssLoaders = (extra) => {
    const loaders = [
        {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
                publicPath: ""
            }
        }, {
            loader: "css-loader"
        },
    ]

    if (extra) {
        loaders.push(extra)
    }

    return loaders;
}

console.log('IsDev:', isDev);

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
    entry: path.join(__dirname, "src", "index.js"),
    output: {
        filename: "[name].[contenthash].js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
    },
    optimization: optimization(),
    devServer: {
        port: 4200
    },
    plugins: [
        new HTMLWebpackPlugin(
            {
                title: 'Evermix',
                template: "./template.html",
                favicon: path.resolve(__dirname, 'favicon.ico'),
                minify: {
                    collapseWhitespace: ! isDev
                }
            }
        ),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin(
            {filename: "src/styles/[name].[contenthash].css"}
        ),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: cssLoaders()
            }, {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/,
                use: cssLoaders('sass-loader')
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|svg)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: 'src/assets/img/[name].[ext]',
                    publicPath: 'assets'
                }
            },
        ]
    }
};
```

зависимости

```
"devDependencies": {
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.3.4",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.4",
    "sass": "^1.32.5",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.16.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.4.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1"
  }
```

структура проекта
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, почему при указании `<img src="/src/assets/img/call-img.svg" alt="">` у меня отображается изображение, а при указании пути к файлу изображения, который подсказывает мне IDE при вводе: `<img src="./assets/img/call-img.svg" alt="">` файл не может быть найден?

Comment: чем отличаются эти два пути?

Comment: @Grundy Прошу прощения, сейчас скорректирую вопрос

Comment: @Grundy Поправил

Comment: а сейчас точно правильно? если есть `/src/` - то картинка показывается или нет?

Comment: @Grundy сейчас точно правильно(. При необходимости в чат могу ссылку на репозиторий в гитхабе отправить

Comment: @Grundy Если есть /src/ то картинка отображается

Answer (score -1):

Все просто, ./ в пути указывает что мы ищем в текущей директории, а /, что ищем в корне проекта. Вы должны указывать путь для папки dist, если смотрите верстку из этой папки. например если ваш главный файл находится в dist, то отновительно папки dist мы можем прописать как / так и ./, так можем и вообще ничего не прописывать. например может быть такой путь "assets/images/1.png" или такой "./assets/images/1.png" или такой '/assets/images/1.png'.

'/' - указывает на корень проекта.
'./' - указывает на нахождение в текущей директории.